# travis-ci not switching to the specified ruby version on an android project build

Tags: android, ruby, rubygems, rvm, travis-ci

I am trying to run a ruby-based tool after a successful travis build for android, and in order to do that I need the rvm version to be 2.0.0, but even when I specified the rvm version in the .travis.yml file, doing bundle install provides the following error:

> Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0

To try and get travis to recognize the ruby version I tried the following:

- Created a .ruby-version file with 2.0.0
- Set the rvm version on .travis.yml like this:

> ```
> language: android
> rvm:  
> - 2.0.0
> ...
> after_script:
> - bundle install
> ```

- Set the ruby version on the Gemfile to match the desired rvm version:

> `ruby: '2.0.0'`
>   
>   None of these settings worked and I always got the above message. Is there something else I'm forgetting to do?

Thanks and Regards,
Federico.-

Answer (score 5):

As per travis-ci support:

"For Android builds, RVM only has 1.9.3 installed (and we do not expand the rvm section in .travis.yml for non-Ruby builds so the specifications in that section are ignored). To get Ruby 2.0.0 for your Android images, use: in your `before_install` section you can add the appropriate lines to install/enable via RVM, like:

```
before_install:
   - rvm install 2.0.0
```

So basically I removed the 'rvm' section on travis.yml and added 'rvm install 2.0.0' on the before_install section and that solved the problem.